# Exit from function on keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function that gets called whenever a user makes a keypress command. It does a bunch of stuff that is context dependent on the project I'm working on, so I'll leave out the source code. But it has an AJAX request. I want to exit from this function, wherever it may be in its execution, and call it again immediately when a new key is pressed. Currently it still finishes executing the function even when a new key is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use abort() to stop any AJAX requests.
Please refer to this page for details.

[Abort AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I'll mark it as correct when it lets me in a couple minutes.

Comment: @EvanHessler my pleasure :)